# How to permanently kill Trigger on Google Spreadsheet Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I Used to set my spreadsheet with some script to has some send email functionality , and I Set a time based trigger to run the script.

yesterday I remove the Spreadsheet , but this morning I still receive the Email which contains the spreadsheet which is i already delete.

i already look up on internet and found [Issue 143: Spreadsheets with time triggered scripts should no longer trigger when spreadsheet is deleted](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=143) post issue on internet , is it the bug still there? or there's a way to permanently remove the trigger and stop the script sending the file that I've deleted before ?

Comment: The issue has not yet been fixed. So, your workaround would be to restore the spreadsheet from trash, delete the trigger first and then delete the spreadsheet

Comment: Has not yet been fixed? Okay thx for suggestion i'll try :)

Comment: @Srik - looks to me like that comment is the answer, can you put it in the answer box. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can first open script editor and delete your trigger and later delete the sheet. That should take care of your issue.